# Replacing value in dataframe if condition is not met

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
 set.seed(10)

 df <- data.frame(a1 = rnorm(7), b1 = rnorm(7), c1 = rnorm(7), 
                  a2 = rnorm(7), b2 = rnorm(7), c2 = rnorm(7))

 df <- round(abs(df), 2)

 df <- df%>%mutate(group1_avg=rowMeans(across(ends_with("1"))), .after=3, 
                   group2_avg=rowMeans(across(ends_with("2"))))

 df <- df%>%mutate(group1_std=rowSds(as.matrix(df[endsWith(names(df), "1")])), .after=4, 
group2_std=rowSds(as.matrix(df[endsWith(names(df), "2")])))

 df <- df%>%relocate(group2_avg, .after=last_col())

 df <- df%>%relocate(group2_std, .after=last_col())

 df
    a1   b1   c1 group1_avg group1_std   a2   b2   c2 group2_avg group2_std
1 0.02 0.36 0.74  0.3733333  0.3601851 2.19 0.10 1.44  1.2433333  1.0587886
2 0.18 1.63 0.09  0.6333333  0.8643109 0.67 0.25 0.36  0.4266667  0.2177919
3 1.37 0.26 0.95  0.8600000  0.5604463 2.12 1.85 1.76  1.9100000  0.1873499
4 0.60 1.10 0.20  0.6333333  0.4509250 1.27 0.08 0.32  0.5566667  0.6293118
5 0.29 0.76 0.93  0.6600000  0.3315117 0.37 0.97 0.65  0.6633333  0.3002221
6 0.39 0.24 0.48  0.3700000  0.1212436 0.69 0.18 1.09  0.6533333  0.4561067
7 1.21 0.99 0.60  0.9333333  0.3089229 0.87 1.38 0.76  1.0033333  0.3308071
```

What I want to do: if any values within columns a1-c1 are 1 standard deviations (group1_std) away from the mean (group1_avg), I want to turn that value into NA. If the value is within this range, I want to leave it alone. I also want to do the same for columns a2-c2 and their corresponding standard deviations and means. In the end I more or less want:

```
 df
    a1   b1   c1 group1_avg group1_std   a2   b2   c2 group2_avg group2_std
1 0.02 0.36  NA   0.3733333  0.3601851 2.19  NA  1.44  1.2433333  1.0587886
2 0.18  NA  0.09  0.6333333  0.8643109  NA  0.25 0.36  0.4266667  0.2177919
3 1.37  NA  0.95  0.8600000  0.5604463  NA  1.85 1.76  1.9100000  0.1873499
4 0.60  NA  0.20  0.6333333  0.4509250  NA  0.08 0.32  0.5566667  0.6293118
5  NA  0.76  NA   0.6600000  0.3315117  NA   NA  0.65  0.6633333  0.3002221
6 0.39 0.24 0.48  0.3700000  0.1212436 0.69  NA  1.09  0.6533333  0.4561067
7 1.21 0.99  NA   0.9333333  0.3089229 0.87  NA  0.76  1.0033333  0.3308071
```

The columns won't always be in this order, so I would prefer to be able to say something like `df[,2:4]` rather than naming them individually. I don't know how to start approaching this, but I would think it involves something with mutate and an `ifelse`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where is `rowSd` from? I can't run this as is, as the function doesn't exist.

Comment: "rowSds" is from the matrixStats package.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the answer you are looking for?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Within_Range_1 = ifelse(group1_std >=1,
                               NA,
                               group1_std),
         Within_Range_2 = ifelse(group2_std >=1,
                                 NA,
                                 group2_std))
```

The output:

```
    a1   b1   c1 group1_avg group1_std   a2   b2   c2 group2_avg
1 0.02 0.36 0.74  0.3733333  0.3601851 2.19 0.10 1.44  1.2433333
2 0.18 1.63 0.09  0.6333333  0.8643109 0.67 0.25 0.36  0.4266667
3 1.37 0.26 0.95  0.8600000  0.5604463 2.12 1.85 1.76  1.9100000
4 0.60 1.10 0.20  0.6333333  0.4509250 1.27 0.08 0.32  0.5566667
5 0.29 0.76 0.93  0.6600000  0.3315117 0.37 0.97 0.65  0.6633333
6 0.39 0.24 0.48  0.3700000  0.1212436 0.69 0.18 1.09  0.6533333
7 1.21 0.99 0.60  0.9333333  0.3089229 0.87 1.38 0.76  1.0033333
  group2_std Within_Range_1 Within_Range_2
1  1.0587886      0.3601851             NA
2  0.2177919      0.8643109      0.2177919
3  0.1873499      0.5604463      0.1873499
4  0.6293118      0.4509250      0.6293118
5  0.3002221      0.3315117      0.3002221
6  0.4561067      0.1212436      0.4561067
7  0.3308071      0.3089229      0.3308071
```

Since standard deviation includes the mean im not sure you need that calculated as well.

Comment: Not quite. For example, for columns a1-c1 in the first row, I want to set any value that is 1 standard deviation away from the mean, to NA. This would mean that any value lower than 0.013 or greater than 0.733 should be set to NA, hence why the value in row 1, column c1 would be NA (as seen in my example).

Comment: Do you mean check each value within the specific columns and if they are 1 SD from the group mean, they should be flagged NA?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.